# How to befriend method from other class that handles this class (incomplete types problem)?

Tags: c++, class, declaration, private-members, friend-function

This sounds like a very obvious question but I can't find anything on the internet. I have a class `other` that handles a `message` in one of its methods. To do so, it has to access a private data member of the message, hence it should be friend of it. But I can't get it to compile. No matter the declaration order, it always complains about types being incomplete. How else would I accomplish such a thing?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:13,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:13,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:10),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Astruct+other%3B%0A%0Aclass+message%0A%7B%0A++++friend+auto+other::handle_message(message)+-%3E+void%3B%0A++++int+private_+%3D+10%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+other%0A%7B%0A++++auto+handle_message(message+msg)+-%3E+void+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22Private+part+of+msg+is+%25d!!%5Cn%22,+msg.private_)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Os%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>

struct other;

class message
{
    friend auto other::handle_message(message) -> void;
    int private_ = 10;
};

struct other
{
    auto handle_message(message msg) -> void {
        printf("Private part of msg is %d!\n", msg.private_);
    }
};

int main() {}
```

Comment: It is obvious that that the class other should be defined before the class message.

Comment: The first and foremost solution is not to require friending.

Comment: Why would you require private access to another class internals? Usually this is not necessary with proper design. I only rarely need it when overloading some (stream) operators. All the other times, not at all or through specific interfaces (abstract baseclasses) that another class can cast to (make access explicit for a specifc purpose instead of the all or nothing of friend)

Comment: Either `message` needs to declare `other` (or its member function) as a `friend`, or `message` needs to provide a `public` getter that retrieves the value of `private_`.     The point of `private` access is that the designer of class `message` is *preventing* access by non-friends.   If class `other` was able to unilaterally override that and pretend friendship, there would be little point in having access control.

Comment: Example of access through a specific interface : https://onlinegdb.com/zpPysvzqP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the following

```
class message;

struct other
{
    auto handle_message(message msg) -> void;
};

/* or just
    struct other
    {
        auto handle_message( class  message msg) -> void;
    };
*/


class message
{
    friend auto other::handle_message(message) -> void;
    int private_ = 10;
};

auto other::handle_message(message msg) -> void {
    printf("Private part of msg is %d!\n", msg.private_);
}
```

That is the class `other` must be defined before the class `message` and its member function `handle_message` must be defined after the definition of the class `message`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <cstdlib>

class message;

struct other
{
    auto handle_message( message msg ) -> void;
};

class message
{
    friend auto other::handle_message( message ) -> void;
    int private_ = 10;
};

auto other::handle_message( message msg ) -> void {
    std::printf( "Private part of msg is %d!\n", msg.private_ );
}

int main()
{
    other().handle_message( message() );
}
```

The program output is

```
Private part of msg is 10!
```

Comment: AH stupid I didn't seperate definition and declaration for handle_message, thx.